# Proving three circles of radius 1 centred at $(0,0), (2,0), (4,0)$ homotopy equivalent to $^1∨^1∨^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homotopy-theory

This is problem 7-15 in Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds. As a hint, he suggests using the fact that a homeomorphism exists taking any n distinct points to any another n distinct points for connected manifolds. How to use the hint given?

Comment: Aren't these two spaces homeomorphic ?

Comment: The first space is like three circles of radius 1 centered at (0,0), (2,0),(4,0), while the second space is three circles intersecting at one point.

Comment: Oh ok so you're not using the usual definiton of $\lor$ (namely, for two pointed spaces $(X,x), (Y,y)$, $X\lor Y$ is a pointed space with point $x=y$). Maybe you should make that explicit in your question

Comment: Thanks. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to use the hint so let me propose an alternative solution.

Let $Y$ be your three circles in $\Bbb R^2$. Check that contracting an arc between $(1,0)$ and $(3,0)$ is an homotopy equivalence, for example using Van Kampen's theorem. Now notice that the resulting space is $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^1$.

Comment: Worse, the hint is false!  It's true for topological manifolds of dimension $\geq 2$, but it's false for $n\geq 4$ on the circle.  Take four points $a,b,c,d$ in a counter clockwise order.  Then there is no homeomorphism of $S^1$ which sends $a$ to $a$, $d$ to $d$, and swaps $b$ and $c$.  To be fair, perhaps Lee intends the hint to be used with $n\leq 3$, where it is true, but like you, I don't see how to use it.